# Deja Dup is not working

Tags: backup

Deja Dup is not working.  It says:

```
Failed to execute child process "duplicity" (No such file or directory)".
```

Answer (score 1):

Installing missed packages should fix that.

```
sudo apt-get install duplicity python-gi
```